# guardar varios parametros en una solo session

Tags: php, array, session

Tengo una duda con `PHP`, realizo un formulario con un solo `input`, y con 2 botones, uno de guardar y otro de recoger.

La idea es que al darle al botón guardar se guarde en una `$_SESSION`, tantas variables como se escriban en `input`, pero resulta que solo me guarda la ultima variable escrita.

Pongo algo del código.

index.php

```
<body>
<form action="guardar.php" method="post">


    <br/><br/>
    <h1>Escriba una palabra o un numero</h1><br/>
    <input type="text" name="datoparametro" VALUE="" id="datoparametro"><br/><br/>


    <input type="submit" name="ok" VALUE="guardar"><br/>


</form>

<input type="submit" value="recojer" onclick="location='recojer.php'"/> <br/>
<input type="submit" value="borrar" onclick="location='borrar.php'"/>
</body>
```

guardar.php

```
<?php

session_start();
$midato=$_POST["datoparametro"];


$_SESSION["dato"]=$midato;


if(isset($_SESSION["dato"])){

  $midato=$_SESSION["dato"]+ 1;
}
else{
    $midato=array();
    $midato[]=$_POST["datoparametro"];
    $_SESSION["dato"]=$midato
}

?>
```

Comment: ¿podrías publicar el código de lo que quieres hacer? No entiendo bien el problema.

Comment: Podrías ampliar tu pregunta con el código que tienes para guardar las variables?

Comment: Creíste poner algo de código, pero no hay tal código. Por favor edita la pregunta poniendo el código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La respuesta es simple, y no necesitas verificar si existe $_SESSION["dato"]...

```
<?php
    session_start();       
    $_SESSION["dato"][]=$_POST["datoparametro"];
?>
```

Comment: con tu respuesta, el abrir el array con corchetes en blanco no me los acepta, me dice que no es soportado por los strings

Answer (score 2):

Si la idea es guardar en la variable de session `$_SESSION["dato"]` tantos valores como se envían en `$_POST["datoparametro"]`, podrías hacer lo siguiente:

- Validar si la variable `$_SESSION["dato"]` existe. En el caso de que no exista, la inicializamos como un `array`.
- Luego agregamos el valor enviado en `$_POST["datoparametro"]` al arreglo en la variable `$_SESSION["dato"]`.

Ejemplo:

```
<?php

session_start();

// Si no existe, la inicializamos
if (empty($_SESSION["dato"])) {
    $_SESSION["dato"] = array();
}

// Agregamos el nuevo valor al arreglo
$_SESSION["dato"][] = $_POST["datoparametro"];
?>
```

Comment: gracias ,al final tu manera es la que mejor me ha ido, pero gracias a todos

Comment: @racxo si está respuesta solucionó tu problema, considera aceptarla marcando el **✓** que está a la izquierda de la respuesta, debajo de las flechas de votación (no se te descuenta nada por eso -todo lo contrario)

Comment: @racxo, si aún crees que esta es mejor respuesta, puedes marcarla como la correcta haciendo click en el `✓`

Answer (score 0):

Para poder pasar la variable como sesión este código debes realizar :

```
if ($ldapbind) {        
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['name']=$_POST["t1"]; 
           echo" alert('Bienvenido Al Panel de  Administracion de Usuario.');
            window.location.href='panel.php'; "; 
    }
```

Luego en tu otra pagina donde va recepcionar el nombre antes de HTML debes colocar este código:
Ademas es con un poco de seguridad si caso la otra persona conoce el nombre de tu otra pagina pero no se ha logeado con ese código no podrá acceder, solo podrá acceder si esta logeado.

```
session_start(); 
if (!isset($_SESSION['name'])) { 
    header("location: index.php");
}
```